# Activity gets restarted after there's a change in firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-activity

When I try to write, update, delete or change any type of data to my realtime firebase database, an activity gets recreated automatically. I checked online for the solution but all didn't work. Something about SingleValueEventListener. What could I be doing wrong? Below is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean gps_enabled;

    assert lm != null;
    gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    relativelayout = findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);

    signoutRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MakeUpArtists_Info").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("device_token");

    username = findViewById(R.id.username);
    greetings = findViewById(R.id.greetings);

    sign_out = findViewById(R.id.sign_out);
    sign_out.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            signoutRef.setValue("no_token");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Signing out...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            Intent log_out = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(log_out);
            finish();

        }
    });


    ongoing_task = findViewById(R.id.latest_task);
    ongoing_task.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            PressRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MakeUpArtists_Info").child(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid()).child("Ongoing");
            PressRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String c_id = dataSnapshot.child("cu_id").getValue().toString();

                    Intent choose_mua_intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OngoingTask.class);
                    choose_mua_intent.putExtra("customer_id", c_id);
                    startActivity(choose_mua_intent);
                    finish();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    });

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MakeUpArtists_Info").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Log.d("Culprit", "Yes, it is me 1");

            String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
            String name = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();

            if (!image.equals("default")) {

                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.no_image_two).into(profile);
            }

            username.setText(name);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    location_switch = findViewById(R.id.location_switch);

    switchRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MakeUpArtists_Info").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("online");
    currentUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("MakeUp_Artists").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

    setUpLocation();

    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    switchRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Log.d("Culprit", "Yes, it is me 2");

            String online = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            if (online.equals("true")) {
                location_switch.setChecked(true);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline();
            } else {
                currentUserRef.onDisconnect().removeValue();
                location_switch.setChecked(false);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline();

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    if (gps_enabled) {
        location_switch.setClickable(true);
    } else {
        location_switch.setClickable(false);
    }

    location_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean IsOnline) {
            if (IsOnline) {
                switchRef.setValue(true);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline();
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                buildLocationRequest();
                buildLocationCallback();
                fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallBack, Looper.myLooper());
                displayLocation();
                Snackbar.make(relativelayout, "You are currently available", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                switchRef.setValue(false);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline();
                fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallBack);
                currentUserRef.onDisconnect().removeValue();
                mCurrent.remove();
                mMap.clear();
                Snackbar.make(relativelayout, "You just went offline", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    mArtists = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("MakeUp_Artists");
    geoFire = new GeoFire(mArtists);

    onGoingRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MakeUpArtists_Info").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Ongoing");
    onGoingRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Log.d("Culprit", "Yes, it is me 3");

            String ongoing = dataSnapshot.child("alert_issue").getValue().toString();

            if (ongoing.equals("Your request was accepted")) {
                location_switch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ongoing_task.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                location_switch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ongoing_task.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildLocationCallback();
                buildLocationRequest();
                if (location_switch.isChecked()) {
                    displayLocation();
                }
            }
    }
}

private void setUpLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
        }, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

    } else {
        buildLocationRequest();
        buildLocationCallback();
        if (location_switch.isChecked()) {
            displayLocation();


        }

    }
}

private void buildLocationCallback() {
    mLocationCallBack = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                CommonClass.mLastLocation = location;
                displayLocation();
            }
        }
    };
}

private void buildLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
}

private void displayLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }

    fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            CommonClass.mLastLocation = location;

            if (CommonClass.mLastLocation != null) {
                if (location_switch.isChecked()) {
                    final double latitude = CommonClass.mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                    final double longitude = CommonClass.mLastLocation.getLongitude();

                    geoFire.setLocation(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(),
                            new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {

                                    Log.d("Culprit", "Yes, it is me 4");

                                    if (mCurrent != null)
                                        mCurrent.remove();
                                    mCurrent = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                                            .title("Your current location")
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.rec)));

                                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 15.0f));

                                    /*rotateMarker(mCurrent, 360, mMap);*/
                                }
                            });
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("ERROR", "Cannot get your location");
            }
        }
    });


}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    try {
        boolean isSuccess = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.makeup_aid_map)
        );

        if (!isSuccess)
            Log.e("MUA - CUSTOMER", "Map style failed!");


    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setTrafficEnabled(false);
    mMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);
    mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(false);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    buildLocationRequest();
    buildLocationCallback();
    fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallBack, Looper.myLooper());
}
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't crash. Why would you say it crashes.

Comment: `startActivity(choose_mua_intent);` starts a new activity

Comment: Yes of course, @Peter Haddad. But when I just switch off my location with the "location_switch variable", the activity gets recreated.

Comment: I mean the activity restarts.

Comment: Look through my code, please. The "location switch" makes the activity restart all over again. But actually, the location switch puts some data into the database, but in that moment, the activity also restarts. Why?

Comment: Something looks circular: when `location_switch` is cleared, `switchRef` is set to false - which has a listener and if false sets `location_switch` to false ....and so on...

Comment: Exactly. But it writes to the database. And when that happens, it restarts the activity. Am I doing anything wrong or it's from firebase?

Comment: Either it's crashing, or you're calling `startActivity()`. You can determine the conditions under which `startActivity()` is called by putting a breakpoint on it.

Comment: I said it's not crashing. The activity gets restarted upon any changes to the database. Why do you insist it's crashing?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: @PerfectUpdates You may want to examine my comment more carefully. It could be re-stated this way: "If A is not happening, then B must be happening". You seem confident that "A" is not happening, so that leaves you with "B". Since you seem to be wondering _why_ "B" is happening, I suggested you put a breakpoint on it. This technique can be used to help you understand your program's control flow.